# ExtJs - delay in rendering column list in table when adding dropdown from column list

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I'm trying to make a drop down button with a list of columns in a table. I created this code, but the problem is that when the code is executed, there are no columns in `this` yet, so the array is `empty`. The button is generated but without any options. The solution is to add `setTimeout`, the data arrives, but the button does not appear because the application has already rendered the container in which it is located. Second thing, `setTimeout` is not a very good solution.

```
Ext.define('ExtModules.ToolbarItems.ManageColums', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  mixins: { formFields: 'ExtModules.Components.GenericForm' },

  manageColumns() {
      // this.getColumns is []
      const columnMenuItems = this.getColumns().map((column) => {
      console.log(column)
      return {
        xtype: 'menucheckitem',
        text: column.text,
        checked: true,
        handler: (item) => {
          const dataIndex = column.dataIndex;
          const columnInstance = this.getColumnManager().getHeaderByDataIndex(dataIndex);

          if (columnInstance) {
            columnInstance.setVisible(item.checked);
          }
        },
      };
    });
  
    return Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
      text: 'Columns',
      menu: Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        items: columnMenuItems,
      }),
    });

  },
})
```

...

```
Ext.define('ExtModules.Helpers.ToolbarHelper', {
  mixins: {
    ...
    manageColumns: 'ExtModules.ToolbarItems.ManageColums',
    ...
  },
  requires: ['Ext.ux.exporter.Exporter'],

  setUpExtensionBar(extensions, position) {
    const extensionBar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
      layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch',
      },
      // height: 40,
      dock: position || 'top',
      items: extensions,
    })
    this.addDocked(extensionBar)
  },
...
```

...

```
Ext.define('ExtModules.Base.DashboardModule', {
  mixins: {
    extensions: 'ExtModules.ToolbarItems.SettingsEditor',
    toolbarHelper: 'ExtModules.Helpers.ToolbarHelper',
  }, .....
```

my current use case

```js
Ext.define('ExtModules.ToolbarItems.ManageColums', {
    xtype: 'managecolumns',
    
    manageColumns() {
      const button = {
        xtype: 'button',
        name: 'Manage',
        text: 'Manage Columns',
        handler: (btn, e) => {
          if (btn.menu.items.length === 0) {
            const menuItems = this.createList()

            btn.menu.removeAll()
            btn.menu.add(menuItems)
            btn.showMenu()
          }
        },
        menu: {
          xtype: 'menu',
          items: [],
        }
      };
      return button
    },

    createColumnMenuItems(button) {
      const menuItems = this.createList();
      const newMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        items: this.createColumnMenuItems(menuItems),
      });
  
      button.setMenu(newMenu);
  },
  
  createList() {
    const columns = this.getColumnManager().getColumns();

    return columns.map((column) => ({
      xtype: 'menucheckitem',
      text: column.text,
      checked: true,
      cls: 'toolbar-helper__custom-checkbox-menu-item',
      handler: (item) => {
        const dataIndex = column.dataIndex;
        const columnInstance = this.getColumnByDataIndex(dataIndex);
  
        if (columnInstance) {
          columnInstance.setVisible(item.checked);
        }
      },
    }));
  },
  getColumnByDataIndex(dataIndex) {
    const columnManager = this.getColumnManager();
    const targetColumn = columnManager.getColumns().find((column) => column.dataIndex === dataIndex);
  
    return targetColumn;
  },
  
  getColumnManager() {
    return this.getHeaderContainer().getHeaderAtIndex(0);
  },
})

/* toolbar.js
Ext.define('ExtModules.Helpers.ToolbarHelper', {
  mixins: {
    ...
    manageColumns: 'ExtModules.ToolbarItems.ManageColumns',
  },
  requires: ['Ext.ux.exporter.Exporter'],
*/
```

Is anyone able to help me with this? I don't really have any idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below sample based on your use case,

```
Ext.define('ExtModules.Store.SampleStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'age'],
    data: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        age: 30
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jane',
        age: 25
    }],
});

Ext.define('ExtModules.Grid.SampleGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: 'ExtModules.Store.SampleStore',
    id: 'SampleGrid',
    columns: [{
        text: 'ID',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        hidden: true,
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        hidden: true,
        flex: 1
    }],
});

Ext.define('ExtModules.ToolbarItems.ManageColumns', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'managecolumns',
    initComponent() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Columns',
                menu: this.createColumnMenu(),
            }, ],
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    createColumnMenu() {
        return Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
            items: this.createColumnMenuItems(),
        });
    },
    createColumnMenuItems() {
        const columns = this.columns || [];
        return columns.map((column) => {
            return {
                xtype: 'menucheckitem',
                text: column.text,
                checked: !column.hidden, // Set initial value based on column visibility
                handler: (item) => {
                    const dataIndex = column.dataIndex;
                    const columnInstance = this.getColumnByDataIndex(dataIndex);
                    if (columnInstance) {
                        columnInstance.setVisible(item.checked);
                    }
                },
            };
        });
    },

    getColumnByDataIndex(dataIndex) {
        const grid = Ext.getCmp('SampleGrid');
        const columnManager = grid.getColumnManager();
        const targetColumn = columnManager.getColumns().find((column) => column.dataIndex === dataIndex);

        return targetColumn;
    },

    getColumnManager() {
        return Ext.getCmp('SampleGrid').getHeaderContainer().getHeaderAtIndex(0); // Adjust 'yourGridId'
    },
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch() {
        var sampleStore = Ext.create('ExtModules.Store.SampleStore');
        var sampleGrid = Ext.create('ExtModules.Grid.SampleGrid', {
            store: sampleStore,
        });
        var manageColumnsToolbar = Ext.create('ExtModules.ToolbarItems.ManageColumns', {
            columns: sampleGrid.columns,
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: [sampleGrid, manageColumnsToolbar],
            }],
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: thanks, I adapted it to my solution and it works. however, the problem is that when entering the screen it does not retrieve information about which column is visible and which is hidden. It always displays all checkboxes as checked

Comment: Please update your complete use case in the fiddle

Comment: I've just added @shae

Comment: @HarryBaker In the createColumnMenuItems method , set the initial value of the checked property based on the visibility of each column.I have updated the logic in the response please check and if this helps accept the answer!